# Json Converter not recognising null attributes and throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.5, json.net

Say I have a sample Json format string as

```
string per1 = @"[{""Email"":""AAA"",""mj_campaign_id"":""22"",""mj_contact_id"":""PPP"",""customcampaign"":""AAA"",""blocked"":""22"",""hard_bounce"":""PPP"",""blocked"":""22"",""hard_bounce"":""PPP""},"
                           + @"{""Email"":""BBB"",""mj_campaign_id"":""25"",""mj_contact_id"":""QQQ"",""customcampaign"":""AAA"",""blocked"":""22"",""hard_bounce"":""PPP"",""blocked"":""22""},"
                           + @"{""Email"":""CCC"",""mj_campaign_id"":""38"",""mj_contact_id"":""RRR"",""customcampaign"":""AAA"",""blocked"":""22"",""hard_bounce"":""PPP""}]";
```

I am trying to deserialize it using

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(per1);
```

Its working fine as long as all the rows of the string has values for the following attributes Email, mj_campaign_id, mj_contact_id, customcampaign, blocked, hard_bounce, error_related_to, error. But when I skip some sttribute values in some rows its throwing an error saying

Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you building manual JSON?

Comment: Its a test application. The application will actually read from a webpage containing these attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you are not assigning a value to an object, which you need to do.  If you remove the value, at least add an empty string.

THAT SAID!
Herein lies the danger of manually building JSON strings.  You should always avoid it if you can.  If you are reading from a web page, that web page should serialize the payload for you, and then you should deserialize it with whatever you are using to pull in the payload (controller, restful service, etc).  The beauty of .NET is that it handles all of this plumbing for you and you really are going to run into painful issues if you try to reinvent the .NET wheel